# about printing a single character in an array without using for loop in c language

Tags: c, string

Recived blank screen output in c compiler when i used this simple code

what i need is to print a single specified character in array (without any type loop)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int str[10] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};


  printf("\n%s", str[1]); //hoping to print e
  
  return 0;
}
```

sharing an article or something about it very appreciated

Comment: `printf("%c\n", str[1])` is correct. `%s` expects a `char*` and a `\0`-terminated string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation for the function `printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), the `%s` format specifier is for printing a string. If you want to print a single character, you should use the `%c` format specifier instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int str[10] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};

    printf( "%c\n", str[1] ); //hoping to print e
  
    return 0;
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
e
```

It is also worth nothing that it is normal to use the data type `char` instead of `int`, when dealing with integers representing characters:

```
char str[10] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
```

Since we are now using `char` instead of `int`, we can also initialize the array from a string literal, which is simpler to type:

```
char str[10] = "hello";
```

Both declarations define an array of exactly 10 `char` elements, with the last 5 elements initialized to `0`, i.e. a null character.